# How to combine Unit and Nothing?

Tags: kotlin

I would like to disable a setter. Therefor I marked it private and the only thing it does is throwing an exception.

```kotlin
private val authorization = object {
    val header = "Authorization"
    var granted: Boolean = false
        set (value) {
            field = value
            if (granted)
                preferences.save (username, password)
            else
                recalc_basicauth = true }
    var username: String = ""
        set (value) {
            granted = false
            field = value }
    var password: String = ""
        set (value) {
            granted = false
            field = value }
    private var recalc_basicauth = true
    private val basicauth_prefix = "Basic "
    var basicauth: String = basicauth_prefix
        get() {
            if (recalc_basicauth) {
                field = basicauth_prefix + Base64.getEncoder()
                    .encodeToString ("$username:$password".toByteArray())
                recalc_basicauth = false }
            return field }
        private set (value) : Nothing {
            throw IllegalArgumentException ("basicauth must not set directly") } }
```

A function, that never returns should have the return value of [`Nothing`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-nothing.html). But a setter must have the return value of `Unit`.

Is there a way to combine both?

Comment: What's wrong with returning `Unit`? You just don't like the less good data and control flow analyses?

Comment: why are you using `var` if you don't need a setter, change it to `val` and remove `set`

Comment: @Sweeper The whole use of a property is wrong here. But I am still curious, if there should be an inheritance between `Unit` and `Nothing`, because they are somehow related.

Comment: @IR42 If I use `val`, the property has no storage, but I use the storage as a cache.

Comment: Well, since `Nothing` is a subtype of every type, it is a subtype of `Unit`.

Comment: @Sweeper So the code would work, if the relation would be in the oposite direction. But it is probably way too esoteric to brood about the inheritance relationship of shades of none.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? It is mandated by the spec that setters must have `kotlin.Unit` as their return type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is mandated in the [spec](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/declarations.html#getters-and-setters) that setter return types must be of type `Unit`:

> As mentioned before, a property declaration may include a custom
> getter and/or custom setter (together called accessors) in the form of
>
> ```
> var x: T = e
>     get(): TG { ... }
>     set(anyValidArgumentName: TS): RT { ... }
> ```
>
> These functions have the following requirements
>
> - ...
> - RT ≡ kotlin.Unit ;
> - ...

You don't *have* to explicitly mark the setter as returning `Nothing`. I'd just do this:

```
private set (value) = 
    throw IllegalArgumentException ("basicauth must not set directly")
```

The setter will be declared as returning `Unit`, but the only thing that you don't get is the control flow and data flow analyses that comes with `Nothing`, like the friendly "unreachable code" warning when you do something like this:

```
basicauth = ""
println("Foo") // you don't get an unreachable code warning here
```

Or the intelligent null analysis that Kotlin does:

```
if (something == null) { basicAuth = "" }
// safely use something, because an exception would have been thrown
```

But frankly, the above example is quite silly. I doubt anyone would write code like that and expect it to work

Alternatively, you can disable the setter by adding another property:

```
private var basicAuthCache: String = basicauth_prefix

val basicauth: String
    get() {
        if (recalc_basicauth) {
            basicAuthCache = basicauth_prefix + Base64.getEncoder()
                .encodeToString ("$username:$password".toByteArray())
            recalc_basicauth = false
        }
        return basicAuthCache
    }
```